# Asynchronous file upload response never makes it back to client (or takes longer than it should)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

We are having an issue with our Application where we are never getting a response back to the client (Chrome in this case) from a pretty simple asynchronous file upload call. It also bogs down our server for up to 2 minutes. Below is our Controller method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string id, string fileName)
{


    string[] allowedAttachmentFileTypes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentsSetting"].Split(',');
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    bool extensionAllowed = allowedAttachmentFileTypes.Any(allowedAttachmentFileType => allowedAttachmentFileType.ToLower().Trim() == extension.ToLower().Trim());

    if (extensionAllowed)
    {
        var fileResult = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        //...do async database stuff with fileResult

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    else
    {
        //this never makes it back to client
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType)
        {

            Content = new StringContent(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AttachmentsSetting"])
        };
        return response;
    }

}
```

What I am mainly concerned with at the moment is that we are testing with what would in our system be an invalid file extension so that it would go to the else clause and just return the bad response.  When we put a breakpoint here, it hits our controller and eventually hits our return in the else clause, and works as expected, but in Chrome, it still shows "Pending".

Another thing is it seems to be dependent on the size of the file we send to the Controller, even though we don't really do anything with the file unless the extension is valid.  An invalid file that is 26,939KB never gives us a server response.  While one that is 17,432KB gave us one, although it still took a minute.

One other thing I should add:  This is more inconsistent, but at times if we do have a valid file extension on a bigger file, like say the 26,939KB one, we would get "There is no longer an HttpContext available." when trying to copy the file to the file system

Comment: Why not check the file extension client side before you upload?

Comment: We are actually doing this now to improve the user experience, but the possibility still remains that there could be a DDoS if they upload a valid file. Just the act of sending a file to the Controller seems to slows us down.  Also updated the post with one other error we are getting.

Comment: If you can assume that an invalid extension is an error that the UI should never allow, you could use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45542645/120955) to abort the request.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a firewall issue.  Nothing code related.